# How can i use database in my android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android access to remote SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database)

I am going to make android app which has lots of database, can I put it (only database) on server & using my app can i access those database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install a local server like WAMP on your system (if you are using windows).
Download WAMP from www.wampserver.com/en/. according to your system configs.

> If WAMP Server not installing properly and showing error message that msvcr100.dll file is missing then download the msvcr100.dll file from [here](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100) and paste it in **System32** folder of your system.

All steps for setting up the server and executing code in android are given nicely in [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Can I use other database in android?? (e.g Oralce,SQL server)

Answer (score 0):

Android default database is SQLIte. so use android default one then only you handle database easily.
Please verify this url : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html