# Working with stored procedures in android(calling and storing)

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to know the steps that needs to be completed to call a stored procedure in sql server from my android app and using it for saving and validation.

Comment: You normally wouldn't, not directly.  You'd have a web service inbetween you and the database, and that service will call the stored procedure.  Otherwise you'd have to make your database access open to the world, and that's never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question a while ago. Please see this link: [Android access to remote SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database/10682780#10682780) on why what you are trying to do is a bad idea. Generally speaking using web services is going to be route to go and exposing your database directly to the internet is going to inviting problems.

If you are feeling experimental and want to try out some real socket programming you can also use sockets and create your own protocols.