# Android Communications link failure when minSdkVersion is greater than 9

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

Using the mysql-connector-java.5.1.26-bin.jar to connect my android app to a remote mysql host. Problem is, anything above minSdkVersion 9 casuses the "Communications link failure". If I have it set to 9, it connects fine and gets database information. Here's my connection code:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        while(rs.next()) {              
           ....
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: This is not the recommended way of communicating between a Android device and a MySQL server. There is lots that can go wrong. See this link for suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database/10682780#10682780

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I was trying to do a network connection in the main activity. For those that might have the same problem, look into using asynctask to complete the connection.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Development Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu14.04
- IDE: Eclipse Luna
- DB: MySQL5.1.73

Firstly,I put the code below in OnCreate method:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();       
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,
                        password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();            
String sql = "select distinct Action from attributes";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

The connection code is OK, But It will occur:

> communication link failure.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

So it must be wrong in something else. After trying various method, and solve it using android [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Just put the code relative to operating mysql in Class that extends AsyncTask.
Below is my code:

```
private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,
                        password);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "select distinct Action from attributes";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                List<String> actions = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    actions.add(rs.getString("Action"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MySQLConnection", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.