# Android mobile application to capture data from form and input into a MySQL database LAMP

Tags: java, mysql, android

I'am new to Android app development. I want to create a mobile application that has two entry fields.
i.e:
FirstName and
LastName

and will input into `MySQL` database.
 Is there a basic source code example available to achieve  something like this? how would i create something like this?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: How is this related to php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database/10682780#10682780 will explain to you some steps on how to achieve this.

Comment: please show us what you got so far ?

Answer (score 0):

[Android access to remote SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database/10682780#10682780) will explain to you why you dont want to connect a android device directly to a SQL server of any kind. It is a bad idea.

Go do some research on how to create either a SOAP or REST service and how to consume them in Android. Here is a article on [REST](https://sites.google.com/site/androidosbeginning/cosuming-restful-webservice-in-android) and here is a article on [SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android).

Once you can create web services either SOAP or REST then any device can use your service not just android.

There is some great way to generate web services for this example by using Netbeans and Eclipse. Here is a great [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) tutorial to get you started.