# Online DB on windows phone 8

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm want to save some datas on an online db. How can I connect to an online database (SQLSERVER) on **windows phone 8** ?
Thank you.

Comment: try azure, see if they have sql compact there.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont connect directly to a database from a mobile phone. Use webservices either SOAP or REST. You are opening a can of worms by exposing your database directly to the internet.

Also if you want to expand and include other phones i.e. iPhone and Android to your database then you are going to have lots of different code to maintain.

See this answer [Android access to remote SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679588/android-access-to-remote-sql-database/10682780#10682780) for more information about this.